# Not always getting mayorship notification with checkins

Tags: foursquare

Recently I've noticed that on occasion I do not get a mayorship notification when I check-in to certain venues. Doesn't seem to matter if the mayor is a friend or not. Haven't really tested if days away from mayorship makes a difference, but it never used to. I used to always get the mayorship notification regardless.

Just wondering if that's expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware if it's expected or not, but the mayorship stanza in check-in notifications is definitely optional and you'll want to hit the venue details if you'd like to fetch mayorship details.